# How to measure the similarity between three vectors?

Tags: sas

How to measure the similarity between three vectors? 
Suppose I have three students and their subjects marks. 
Student 1 (12,23,43,35,21)
Student 2 (23, 34, 45, 25.17) and 
Student 3 (34, 43, 22, 11, 39)
now I want to measure the similarity between these three students. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a better question for stats.stackexchange.com rather than here. You should also specify which software you are using, R or SAS will have very different answers.

Comment: Hey, I am using SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You want similarity, not dissimilarity. The latter is available in numerous functions, some noted in the comments. The most commonly used metric for dissimilarity is Euclidean distance.

To measure similarity, you could use the `simil(...)` function in the `proxy` package in R, as shown below. Assuming that the scores are in the same order for each student, you would combine the scores into a matrix row-wise, then:

```
Student.1 <- c(12, 23, 43, 35, 21)
Student.2 <- c(23, 34, 45, 25, 17)
Student.3 <- c(34, 43, 22, 11, 39)
students <- rbind(Student.1,Student.2,Student.3)

library(proxy)
simil(students,method="Euclidean")
#               Student.1  Student.2
# Student.2 0.04993434           
# Student.3 0.02075985 0.02593140
```

This calculates the Euclidean distance for every student vs. every other student, and converts that to a similarity score using

> sim = 1 / (1+dist)

So if the scores for two students are identical, their similarity will be 1.

But this is only one way to do it. There are 48 similarity/distance metrics coded in the `proxy` package, which can be listed using:

```
pr_DB$get_entries()
```

You can even code your own metric, using, e.g.,

```
simil(students,FUN=f)
```

where `f(x,y)` is a function that takes two vectors as arguments and returns a similarity score defined as you like. This might be relevant if, for example, some courses were "more important" in the sense that you wanted to weight differences wrt those courses more highly than the others.